# Would like to Show the form N number of times when user enter a Number in a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I will have a text box where user can enter 0-9999 . If  the user enters 10 i would like to load a Form. This form will have some controls and buttons namely Save . If user enter data and click on save i would like to clear the fields and have to show that form again up to the number of times(as per i said 10) corresponding to the value entered by the user in the textbox.

Comment: You want to show a Form (up to) 9999 times?

Comment: Henk If user gives the values as 9999 means i have to

Comment: @Moon : how can i attach the code so that i will attach the files what i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of showing the form 0-9999 times, you could pass the value (0-9999) to the form, and clear the fields on that form for 0-9999 times after user click on save and then close it.

e.g:

```
//on main form:
int i = 0; 
//parse the textbox1.text to int and check the result:
if(!int.TryParse(textbox1.Text,out i)||i<0||i>9999)
{
  //incorrect int value 
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value");
}
else //correct int value
{
  subform mysub=new subform(i);
  subform.ShowDialog();
}
//on your subform:
int timebeforeclose=0;
public subform(int count)
{
  timebeforeclose=count;
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //1.save your data or whatever...
  //2.empty any fields you want..
  //update timebeforeclose:
  timebeforeclose--;
  //check the timebeforeclose:

  if(timebeforeclose==0)
  {
    this.Close(); //close this form when reaches the specified number.
  }      
}
```

Comment: One more help if close the form i would like to show the same from until and un-less condition matches

Comment: @Dorababu, Please see my updated answer, should move `timebeforeclose--` before check it.

Comment: One more clarification i handled this under textbox_leave event if user leaves with out entering a value i am getting an error what to do for that

Comment: @Dorababu, Please see my updated answer, you can check the text while parsing it into the int. BTW: you can also restrict the user to enter digits only.

Comment: you need to check the value is in your range (0-9999) before pass it to your subform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would probably be a simple for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i < textboxvalue; i++)
{
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i=0; i < textboxvalue; i++)
{
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
}
```

This will show form n times but will appear once visible form is closed. ShowDialog stops the execution at parent.

Rather use `form.Show()`

Comment: First, you could have simply commented on my answer, instead of copy/pasting most of it into your own answer. Second, that's exactly the behaviour he's looking for; opening n forms, one at a time.

Comment: @Nellius I thought this will give more info. Sorry I stole your code :)